# How many executors has deployed airflow in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am new in Airflow and kubernetes.

I have deployed airflow following this guide: https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-apache-airflow-azure-postgresql-redis/

I understand that the executor is celeryExecutor. I tried to change it to kubernetesexecutor but I really don´t know how to do it.

I have read that the celery executor creates static workers and kubernetes executor create a pod for each task.

What I don´t know is how many workers has my celery executor deployed and how to increase them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you used the [Bitnami Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/airflow) to deploy Airflow into Kubernetes.

In the values file, the config setting `airflow.worker.replicas` controls how many worker pods will be deployed. The default value is 2.